# How to insert a data frame into Cassandra in Scala

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

I have a data frame with as shown below and want to insert this data into cassandra table

```
+---------+------+-----------+
| name    |  id  |  city     |
+---------+------+-----------+
| sam     | 123  |  Atlanta  |
| John    | 456  |  Texas    |
+---------+------+-----------+
```

I am using below code but it inserts only last row.

```
df.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
    .options(Map("table" -> "tablename", "keyspace" -> "keyspace"))
    .mode(saveMode = "Append").save(`)
```

How to insert a data frame into Cassandra in Scala?

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided should insert all the rows into Cassandra. There are a few reasons that it might not.

1. That is actually all the data there is, `df` for some reason only
   contains a single row.
2. There are multiple rows but they share the same Partition key,
   this means that subsequent writes will overwrite the initial write.
3. An exception is being thrown, this should be obvious in the logs.